# Display form's message by remote method using ujs on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, remote-forms

I followed the episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised
and create my cusotm example.
I put the create form in the index, and create a book by remote method

But I have no idea how to put error message in the page.
please give me some example , thanks~

index

```
<%= render 'form' %>

<p>

<table id='books_tbl' class="table">
    <th>id</th>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>sn</th>
    <th>price</th>
    <th>Functions</th>
    <div class="books" id="books">      
        <%= render @existed_books %>
    </div>
</table>
```

the controller

```
# POST /books
# POST /books.json
def create
    @book = Book.new(params[:book])

    respond_to do |format|

        if @book.save
          format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book }
          format.js
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          format.js     
        end
```

create.je.erb

```
<%  unless @book.save   %>

<% else %>

    $('#books_tbl tr:last').after('<%= j render(@book) %>');
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your `books_controller` so that it will always render `create.js.erb` whether the book is persisted or not.

```
def create
  @book = Book.new(params[:book])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @book.save
      format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @book, status: :created, location: @book }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    format.js
  end
end
```

Then, in you `create.js.erb`, you will want to check whether your book is `persited?` or not:

```
<% if @book.persisted? %>
  # ...
<% else %>
  # display the error message
<% end %>
```

Let's say we are going to display the error message in a `<p>` with the `.errors` class:

```
$('<p>').text('<%= @book.errors.full_messages.to_sentence.capitalize %>')
  .prepend('form');
```

The thing is that you will have to remove the errors paragraph every time you render `create.js.erb` so that former errors won't stick around:

```
$('p.errors').remove();
```

All in all, it gives:

```
$('p.errors').remove();

<% if @book.persisted? %>
  # ...
<% else %>
  $('<p>').text('<%= @book.errors.full_messages.to_sentence.capitalize %>')
  .prepend('form')
<% end %>
```